# Type of product/tool for listing Web Services of an IT Department

Tags: web-services, metadata

Note: I am not looking for specific products or recommendations with this question.  I am just wanting to know if this is a "type" of tool with a name for its type.

Our IT Department has a bunch of web services (mostly built in .Net).  We find that we have enough that we struggle to make sure that we don't have people re-creating an already existing web service.

As such, we are looking for a tool that can manage our listing of web services.  Primarily it would allow searching for existing services.  It would also allow entering some descriptive text for each service (maybe even documentation).

I have tried searching for variations on "Service Catalog", but I get a lot of sites that want to provide a listing of all "services".  But when they say services, they are thinking of things that departments can do to help others (ie HR can onboard a new employee, IT can fix your computer, OPS can help with a bug report, etc).

I am hoping that there is a name for the kind of product I need and that someone will tell it to me.  (So I can do some better searching.)

NOTE: I am not looking for an actual recommendation of a tool in this category. (That is off topic for this site as it does not have a canonical answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this may be called an `API Catalog`.  But finding one that just wants to list your services for you is very hard.  They all want to front your services for you (aka an API Gateway).